# Memory leak in setInterval() method

Tags: javascript, html, memory-leaks, highcharts, setinterval

I am creating a javascript based html dashboard. In order to refresh the values in the dashboard charts I have written the following code:

```
var chart, options;

function loadDynamicData() {            
    var data = window.parent.getDynamicData();
    var dataArray = data.split(',');

    for(var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
        chartData[i].data.pop();
        chartData[i].data.push(parseInt(dataArray[i],10));
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    //initialize options here
    setInterval(function () {
        loadDynamicValues(); // loads dynamic values through ajax
                             // and updates options
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }, 300000);
});
```

But the problem is when I run this in the browser for a long time (about 1 hour), the memory being used goes up and the browser becomes unresponsive. If I remove the `setInterval()` method and run the code that is inside for once, then there is no problem.

What can be the problem here?

Comment: And, what does the Highchaets.Chart constructor do?  In general, we can only answer this question if we see all code that is running in the `setInterval()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 it is contained in the HighCharts.js file provided by HighCharts. Its impossible to give all what `Highcharts.Chart()` do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do a chart.destroy() before creating new chart.

> if (chart) chart.destroy;

Here is a link for test. http://www.highcharts.com/tests/?file=memory-chart-destroy

Comment: when the chart is created for the first time it gives an error:`'chart' is null or not an object`

Comment: @silent_warrior: did you mean the first chart object doesn't destroy?

Comment: Sorry if forgot to mention that you should check the uninitialized variable! write like  if (chart) chart.destroy;